# Знаки вопроса вместо пробелов

Tags: php

В базу данных с полей записываются данные. Весь тект записывается нормально но если ввести 2 пробела в базу пишется знак вопроса и выводятся тоже знаки вопроса кодировка страницы utf-8. На странице несколько таких полей причем все работают нормально за исключением 1 поля

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) проверьте тип поля в бд
2) проверьте, через инструменты разработчика браузера отсылается ли этот "вопрос"  на сервер
3) выведите значение перед записью в бд
4) вопрос решается дебагом и лучше Вас его никто не решит.

Чтобы открыть инструменты разработчика кликните по любому элементу на странице правой кнопкой мыши -> просмотреть код элемента. Это и есть, то что вам надо, а конкретно вкладка network, где отображаются все запросы.

[image: img]

Comment: я нуб в этом вопросе в консоли я могу видеть только js. Где это смотреть??

Comment: @Vlad467 дописал